# How to make Python code display properly on mobile phones

Tags: python

Python uses indentation to delimit blocks. It is acceptable for short snippets, but longer pieces of code do not display properly on mobile phones or media with limited width. How to encode Python code in a device-friendly way?

Comment: The question that comes to mind is: why?

Comment: `from __future__ import braces` ?

Comment: Personally, when I'm typing quick scripts on my iPhone, I use 2-space indentation instead of 4-space, but that's more about saving typing than fitting things on the screen. Especially since I get 86 characters in landscape mode on my iPhone 5 (although only 59 in portrait mode), and you shouldn't be writing code that won't fit into 86 characters with 4-space indentation in the first place. And you shouldn't be writing huge scripts on a phone either.

Comment: Use 2-spaces indentation (that's the way on Google App Engine). Braces are "not a chance".

Comment: you can put a `\` in the end of the line to continue with the statement in the next line.